# How to get content from div class using Selenium - Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I want to extract the contents on the left side using the `div class <table__9d458b97>`

I don't want to use xpath to do the job because some contents don't sit in the same position.

```
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome(r'XXXX\chromedriver.exe')
driver2.get("https://www.bloomberg.com/profiles/people/15103277-mark-elliot-zuckerberg")
```

Here is my code using the xpath (how can I use the class?):

```
boardmembership_table=driver2.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/section/div[5]')[0]
boardmembership_table.text
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what's your expected output can post as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of *css_selector*

Your can use the following code

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome


driver2 = Chrome()

driver2.get("https://www.bloomberg.com/profiles/people/15103277-mark-elliot-zuckerberg")

els = driver2.find_elements_by_css_selector('.table__9d458b97[role="table"]')

for el in els:
    print(el.text)

driver2.close()
```

Note that you are using find_element**s**_by_css_selector which will return a list of elements or an empty list if None found.

Comment: What's the difference between css_selector and class?

Comment: With className you can only specify a class. With cssSelector you can use any css attribute and mixe them in one query (i.e ID, Class, Tag, Attribute..). Furthermore, even while using ```class_name method``` internally selenium will convert it to use cssSelector prior to send the request.

Comment: @jancos was this answer helpful for you? Any more questions related to css_selector? If so this answer was helpful, please don't forget to take action: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below xpath, if you want to access Board Membership table.

```
 //*[@id="root"]/div/section/div[h2[.='Board Memberships']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use following sibling to get the div next to the title 'Board Membership' 
like this
'//h2[contains(.,"Board Membership")]//following-sibling::div'

Comment: Also got the error: "IndexError: list index out of range"